# Google Remarketing Tag Not Validating

Tags: google-ads-api

I've implemented Google Remarketing code on a client's site but it's getting an unspecified critical error in the Chrome Tag Assistant plugin. I'm sure I've followed the instructions on how to setup the custom variables correctly. Can anyone see what I've done wrong or shed some light on how to find out what the 'critical error' is?

Here is a code sample -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var google_tag_params = {
    ecomm_prodid: "IS-FRE-FFA",
    ecomm_pagetype: "product",
    ecomm_totalvalue: 19.95};
</script>
/*Rest of the Google suppplied code*/
```

There are lists in the associated Google Adwords account and it says "We haven't detected the AdWords tag on your website" for the Remarketing Tag details box above the lists.

Comment: That doesn't look like an adwords retargeting code to me!! Are you sure you got the conversion code from within adwords??

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the actual page it is hard to be sure - your code snippet looks ok here, but there could be other errors in the rest of the code.  If you could paste the full tag you're using or the site where we can see it in situ that would help diagnose it.

Either way, sometimes the Tag Assistant plugin gets confused by *other* javascript errors on the page - there are some more details on how to validate that the remarketing tag is working correctly at https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/verification